# wordpress lambad expression syntax highlighting

Tags: wordpress

I tried Syntax Highlighter MT in wordpress.org and

```
<pre class="brush: c#; highlight: [1, 3]">
IEnumerable<MyEntity> LoadMyEntities(Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool >> predicate)
{
    return Context.MyEntities.Where(predicate);
}
</pre>
```

gives me [image]

The result has a `bool=""` and some messing codes `<func<myentity...`I guess it messed up the `>>`with sth..Any ideas? Is there any good alternative syntax highlighter?

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is? Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: @dingo_d the highlighter fails with the lambda expression part